# nginx redirect www to non-www for all domains

Tags: nginx, no-www

I have a single page application. all the domains are set on this app (default vhost) and the app works based on domain (one domain per customer). So, the list of domains are constantly changing. domains A record is set to server IP. the vhost config does not have any domain as server_name

now, I want to redirect www to non-www. all tutorials out there is for cases that you know what the domain is.

Comment: can you share configuration file?

Comment: the vhost is set as default @JinnaBalu. all the domains are set to the server IP via DNS A record

Answer (score 0):

For any domain, try it :

```
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)$) {
rewrite / $scheme://$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Just edited, can you re-check the answer  ? @HadiFarnoud

Comment: isn't return 301 better than rewrite?